# Full Join between three tables sharing the same primary key

Tags: sql, join, hive

I want to join three tables to check the number of shared and non shared users on each group.
Ideally I want to produce something similar to this.

[image: Image borrowed from www.mathcentral.uregina.ca]

I have a big table which stores data for many classes, including W, D and P.
To assess if an users is attending more than one class, I would create a sub-query for each group and using a `full join` merge those resulting tables. My issue is that I have to join all three tables on the same primary key (`userpid`).
I've tried to write the query in this way but got an error message from Hive saying the `IS NULL` operator only accepts one argument.

```
select
        isnull(iq1.userpid, iq2.userpid) userpid,
        groupW,
        groupD,
        sum( case when iq2.userpid is not null then 1 else 0 end ) groupP


from
        ( select
                isnull(q1.userpid, q2.userpid) userpid,
                ( case when q1.userpid is not null then 1 else 0 end ) groupW,
                ( case when q1.userpid is not null then 1 else 0 end ) groupD

        from
                -- users who attended class W
                ( select distinct userpid
                from store.attendance
                where classid = 1165
                  and datehour between '2014-04-28 00:00:00' and '2014-04-30 00:00:00'
                 ) q1

                full outer join

                -- users who attended class D
                ( select distinct userpid
                from store.attendance
                where classid= 1174
                  and datehour between '2014-04-28 00:00:00' and '2014-04-30 00:00:00'
                 ) q2

                  on q1.userpid = q2.userpid ) iq1

                full outer join

                -- users who attended class P
                ( select distinct userpid
                from store.attendance
                where classid = 1173
                  and datehour between '2014-04-28 00:00:00' and '2014-04-30 00:00:00'
                 ) iq2

                  on iq2.userpid = iq1.userpid

;
```

Is there another function or way to write the query which I can use to achieve the same goal? 
I can then see the number of shared an non shared users by class, using a series of `case when` calls, or processing it in R or Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest doing this using two layers of aggregation.  First create flags for each class.  Then aggregate by those flags:

```
select has_1165, has_1174, has_1173, count(*) as cnt, min(userpid), max(userpid)
from (select userpid,
             max(case when classid = 1165 then 1 else 0 end) as has_1165,
             max(case when classid = 1174 then 1 else 0 end) as has_1174,
             max(case when classid = 1173 then 1 else 0 end) as has_1173
      from store.attendance
      where classid in (1165, 1173, 1174) and
            datehour between '2014-04-28 00:00:00' and '2014-04-30 00:00:00'
      group by userpid
     ) a
group by has_1165, has_1174, has_1173;
```